# How can I define a function using ArrayFlatten without using SetDelayed?

Tags: function-construction, sparse-arrays

I created a matrix `F2` using `SparseArray` and `ArrayFlatten` as follows:

```
f0[x_, y_] = (3 - (Cos[x] + Cos[y])) PauliMatrix[0] + 5 PauliMatrix[3];
nf = 2; 
F1[x_, y_] = 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {2 nf, 2 nf}] -> {f0[x, y]}, 
    Band[{1, 3}, {2 nf, 2 nf}] -> {7 PauliMatrix[0]}, 
    Band[{3, 1}, {2 nf, 2 nf}] -> {7 PauliMatrix[0]}}];
nt = 2;
IC = SparseArray[{{(2 nf - 1), 1} -> 1, {(2 nf), 2} -> 
     1, {(2 nf - 1), 3} -> 1, {(2 nf), 4} -> 1}, {2 nf, 4 nt}];
F2[x_, y_] = ArrayFlatten[{{F1[x, y], IC}}];
```

As an example, I put `nf=nt = 2`. but what I have is a very large matrix. The problem now is that `F2[0, 0]`  will not substitute `x = 0` and `y = 0` in the matrix. It is working if I define `F2` with `SetDelayed`, i.e., `F2[x_, y_] := ....`. But I do not want to use `SetDelayed` because I have heavy calculations to do with `F2`. So how can I solve this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Normal to make the RHS of the definition of F2 a normal array. The formal arguments were being hidden in the SparseArray:

```
0[x_, y_] = (3 - (Cos[x] + Cos[y])) PauliMatrix[0] + 5 PauliMatrix[3];

nf = 2;

F1[x_, y_] = 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {2 nf, 2 nf}] -> {f0[x, y]}, 
    Band[{1, 3}, {2 nf, 2 nf}] -> {7 PauliMatrix[0]}, 
    Band[{3, 1}, {2 nf, 2 nf}] -> {7 PauliMatrix[0]}}];

nt = 2;

IC = SparseArray[{{(2 nf - 1), 1} -> 1, {(2 nf), 2} -> 
     1, {(2 nf - 1), 3} -> 1, {(2 nf), 4} -> 1}, {2 nf, 4 nt}];

F2[x_, y_] = Normal@ArrayFlatten[{{F1[x, y], IC}}];

F2[a, b]

(* {{8-Cos[a]-Cos[b],0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,-2-Cos[a]-Cos[b],0,7,0,\
0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{7,0,8-Cos[a]-Cos[b],0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,7,0,-2-Cos[\
a]-Cos[b],0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0}} *)
```

Comment: Memoization should work here too, no? Seems this is a problem (long calculation that can’t be done over-and-over-again!) that is tailor made for the technique.